# On application load display empty value in textbox which is bound to GUID property

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

In my WPF XAML I have a text box which is bound to GUID property in viewModel, On application load I want to show this text box as empty instead of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
Following is my XMAL and VM code,

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DocId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True ,
                TargetNullValue= '', NotifyOnValidationError=True}"></TextBox>

private Guid _docId;
    public Guid DocId
    {
        get { return _docId; }
        set
        {
            _docId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DocId");
        }
    }
```

I tried to Set `TargetNullValue= ' '` but it's not working, on application load, text box value in UI is shown as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. I also tried to set `FallbackValue = ''` but the result is still the same. Any suggestion? I'm new to WPF any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your TextBox readonly and the binding one-way if you just need to display a string. Then you raise the change of a dependent string property from the set accessor of the Guid.

In the View:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding GuidStr, Mode=OneWay,
```

In the ViewModel:

```
private Guid _docId;
public Guid DocId
{
    get { return _docId; }
    set
    {
        _docId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DocId");
        OnPropertyChanged("GuidStr");
    }
}
public string GuidStr
{
    get { return _docId.ToString().Replace("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", ""); }
}
```